# C# - Installing .NET 6.0.7 Runtime in Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a question about the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022.

I read a lot articles and Stackoverflow questions about creating an installer of an Visual Studio project.

For example in the Visual Studio Installer Projects you can select at the Prerequisities the second radio button, that the Prerequisities will be downloaded from the same location as my application. I search a lot but i still got an error message that the runtimes are not installed.

(German Error Message)

```
    ERROR: Um "Erforderliche Komponenten von demselben Speicherort wie die Anwendung herunterladen" im Dialogfeld "Erforderliche Komponenten" aktivieren zu können, muss die Datei "net6coreruntime_x64\dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-win-x64.exe" für das Element ".NET Runtime 6.0.7 (x64)" auf den lokalen Computer heruntergeladen werden. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
ERROR: General failure building bootstrapper
ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x80004005
```

I also tried to include the dotnet runtime installer inside the projects, which also did not work.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem and let my program installer also install the runtime?
If yes, please use screenshots and be preciese :)

---

I got a second problem.
assumed i can let the installer also install my runtimes there is a second problem.

If i start the installer without the runtimes, the installer shows me a message that i have to install the runtimes.

is it possible to deactivate the message?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022

Comment: didn't help me to fix the problem

Comment: @CleanBoy why not create a self-contained deployment? Or even a single-file, self-contained executable? You get a *single* file that contains everything needed to run

Comment: `didn't help me to fix the problem ` what does this mean? That's how you add prerequisite runtimes. `that the Prerequisities will be downloaded from the same location as my application` that's a *bad* idea, because after a few months you'll be installing an unsupported, unpatched version that the end user will have to update. In fact, it *will* get updated through Windows Update. The only way to run with a specific version is to use a self-contained deployment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos for the pointers.

Your first question shows that the error is about prerequisites, and the document is to add prerequisites conditional method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022#prerequisites Can you clarify if it doesn't help you?

The second problem is that when there is no runtime, you can try to establish an independent deployment, package it into an executable file independently, and run it on the server without installing any runtime-related things at all.